# Pulling basic mongoengine document definitions into flask-mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I've been using mongoengine for a while now and have a ton of python data processing code that relies on a common set of Object Document Models.

Now I need to access the same mongodb instances from Flask.  I'd like to use the same ODM definitions.

```
class User(Document):
    email = StringField(required=True)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)
```

The problem is that flask-mongoengine requires you to first set up your flask context "db" and *then* build your ODM definitions, inheriting the document class and fieldtypes from "db" instead of the base mongoengine classes.

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.StringField(required=True)
    first_name = db.StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = db.StringField(max_length=50)
```

One solution, I suppose, is to make copies of all of the existing ODM definitions, import "db" from my main flask app, and then prepend everything with "db."   If I do that, I'll have to maintain two sets of nearly identical ODM definitions.

If I simply change everything to the "db." version, that would probably break all of my legacy code.

So I'm thinking there might be a trick using super() on the document classes that can detect whether I'm importing my ODM into a Flask context or whether I'm importing it from a stand alone data processing script.

I'm also thinking I don't want to have to super() every fieldtype for every document, that I should be able to build or reference a common function that took care of that for me.

However, my super() skills are weak.  I'm not even certain if that is the best approach.  I was hoping someone might be able and willing to share some hints as to how to approach this.

Comment: I've run into this issue myself and as you suggest if you want to use the same models in a flask context and a non-flask context it can be tricky. However, all flask-mongoengine is doing is making sure that the mongodb connection is based on the app configuration. My solution was to not use flask-mongoengine at all and just create the connection to mongodb myself in the config file.

Comment: [I'm not sure why this question was downvoted.]  I think the way I'm going to work around this issue is to use a PostgreSQL Foreign Data Wrapper, and then query the MongoDB collections with SQLAlchemy like any of my other PostgreSQL tables.